# Is there a simpler way to specify the return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that takes a functor and calls it with a reference to a Client and returns what the functor returns wrapped in a `Result<T>` (which holds either a T or an error) where T is the return type of the function:

```
template <typename F> requires std::invocable<F, Client&>
auto run(const F& f) -> Result<std::invoke_result<F, Client&>::type> {
  try {
    return f(get_client());
  } catch (Exception &e) { 
    return e.error(); 
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to specify the return type?

Comment: You *could* use something like `decltype(the_expression_to_return)`. However, this case is tricky, since, as written, the whole written return type is actually part of the returned expression (the full-expression contains a conversion to `Result<...>`). The answer would depend on what constructors `Result` has. Ideal would be a tagged constructor of signature like `Result<T>::Result(success_tag, T)`.

Comment: Can you omit the `-> Result<std::invoke_result<F, Client&>::type>` altogether and let the template expansion deduce it (since you're not doing a `&` reference or `const&` const-reference)?

Comment: @Eljay That won't work: the return type specification causes `f(get_client())` to be wrapped by the constructor of `Result<...>`. Without the trailing return type, this code probably doesn't compile.

Comment: Result<T> has a constructor taking a T, and one taking a Status. Since they are different types auto won't work on the function. If I wrap the values in a Result<T> at the return sites then I still need to typedef T in the function. Though, that might look a little nicer.

Comment: There is another issue with this code: `std::invocable` *does not* check that you can call `f(get_client())`. It (basically) checks that you can call `std::invoke(f, get_client())`, and similarly `std::invoke_result` finds the result type of this operation. `std::invoke`, in addition to being able to perform function calls, can also call member function pointers etc. So you should figure out whether you want to work with a bare function call or the full power of `std::invoke` to clarify the question.

Comment: can't you simply `auto run(const F&) -> Result<decltype(f(get_client()))>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, apart from reducing the character count with `decltype` as suggested by Mooing Duck. Perhaps not coincidentally, your `Result` template looks quite similar to [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected), a standard library addition specified by C++23. You can see from the examples there and elsewhere that they look similar to your code, due to the function return type requirements.

However, although it may be verbose, I personally think `std::invoke_result` does add clarity. Since that need not be a trailing return type, my formatting preference would be to either write it on its own line:

```
template <typename F> requires std::invocable<F, Client&>
Result<std::invoke_result_t<F, Client&>>
run(const F& f)
```

or using an alias template, also taking into account the advice by HTNW:

```
template <typename F>
using run_result = Result<std::invoke_result_t<F, Client&>>;

template <std::invocable<Client&> F>
run_result<F> run(const F& f) {
  try {
    return std::invoke(f, get_client());
  } catch (Exception &e) { 
    return e.error(); 
  }
}
```